# JavaScript Почему в слове "sobaka" при выполнении меняется буква "a" в середине(должна меняться последняя)

Tags: javascript, map, replace

нужно в массиве из слов изменить у каждого слова последнюю букву на заглавную.

```
let words = 'sobaka marsik pesik'
let arrayWords = words.split(' ')

arrayWords = arrayWords.map(function(elem, index) {
    let newElem = elem[elem.length-1].toUpperCase()
    let res = elem.replace(elem[elem.length-1], newElem)
    return elem = res})
console.log(arrayWords)//['sobAka', 'marsiK', 'pesiK']
```

Answer (score 3):

`replace` работает через регулярки. И явно не так, как вы ожидали... и как минимум вернёт первое попадание в строке (внимательно почитайте документацию: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace  это не та "замена", о которой вы подумали)

Лучше вернуть комбинацию в виде "часть строки без последнего символа" + "изменённый последний символ". Первую часть можно получить из `slice`, вторую - по длине - 1

```js
let words = 'sobaka marsik pesik';
let arrayWords = words.split(' ');

arrayWords = arrayWords.map(function(elem, index) {    
    return elem.slice(0, -1) + elem[elem.length-1].toUpperCase();
});

console.log(arrayWords)
```

Comment: `arrayWords.map(word => word.replace(/.$/, c => c.toUpperCase()))` или как-то так ☺️

Comment: в алгоритме с индексами пустая строка вызовет исключение, а с регуляркой - нет

Comment: @АлексейР эти предварительные проверочки могут быть до работы с массивом